# How to use default values inside a vanilla javscript plugin

Tags: javascript

Working to a small vanilla js plugin which has some default values/settings. Because the defaults are not in a 1 layer(or how ever you call this) I have a hard time getting it to work. I found a solution online to solve this but this wont work with the structure that i am using.

```
var extend = function () {
var merged = {};
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function (obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) return;
       merged[key] = obj[key];
     
    }
});
return merged;
};
```

The solution above will only work with

```
var settings = {
   name:'john',
   age:'33'
   ...
}
```

This is the structure that I am using now

```
var settings = {
person:[
    {                                   
        name:'john',
        active: 'yes'       
        skills:[
            {
                sports: 'no',
                drinkbeer: 'yes'
            }
        ]
    },
    {                                   
        name:'mary',
        active: 'no'       
        skills:[
            {
                sports: 'yes',
                drinkbeer: 'maybe'
            },
            {
                sports: 'yes',
                drinkbeer: 'maybe'
            }
        ]
    },
],
someValue: 'hello'
}
```

// plugin in action which is missing some values which should be replaced by the above settings

```
var person = new person({
    person:[
        {                                   
            name:'john',
            active: 'yes'       
        },
        {                                     
            skills:[
                {
                    sports: 'yes',
                    drinkbeer: 'maybe'
                },
                {
                    sports: 'yes',
                    drinkbeer: 'maybe'
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    someValue: 'hello'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear.

If you want to get a person data completely, why don't you use

```
let merged = settings.peron.find(x => x.name == name);
// name is the variable you should pass as function argument.
// I used name but of course you should use something unique.
```

If you want to get those values and merge them with another object, let's say

```
let otherObject = { team: "teamName", color: "green" }
```

you can do this, if there is no commen key:

```
let mergedObject = {...merged, ...otherObject};
```

If you want to do something else, you need to add all those details to your question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: no the idea is like for example with jQuery plugin that you can use defauls/settings values when you init the plugin. But when not using values in the init call you should use the default values provided in the plugin it self. Sorry it's hard to explain for me becuase the lack of knowlegde of how these things are called

Comment: https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/blob/master/src/core.js this is where i got the extended function from